# Error:Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded. while using sub2ind

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

Please suggest how to sort out this issue:

```
nNodes = 50400;
adj = sparse(nNodes,nNodes);

adj(sub2ind([nNodes nNodes], ind, ind + 1)) = 1; %ind is a vector of indices
??? Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.
```

Comment: No problems here unless `length(ind)` is fantastically huge...How large is your `ind`?

Comment: It is 1x50148.   I also converted the indices into 1d and did the following:     >>adj(ind1d) = 1;   still getting the same error "
??? Maximum variable size allowed by the program is
exceeded."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
adj = sparse(ind, ind + 1, ones(size(ind)), nNodes, nNodes, length(ind));
```

This worked fine...

And, if we have to access the last element of the sparse matrix, we can access by adj(nNodes, nNodes), but adj(nNodes * nNodes) throws error.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is 32/64-bit related. If you have a 32 bit processor, you can address at most

```
2^32 = 4.294967296e+09
```

elements. If you have a 64-bit processor, this number increases to

```
2^64 = 9.223372036854776e+18
```

Unfortunately, for reasons that are at best vague to me, Matlab does not use this full range. To find out the actual range used by Matlab, issue the following command:

```
[~,maxSize] = computer
```

On a 32-bit system, this gives

```
>> [~,maxSize] = computer
maxSize =
    2.147483647000000e+09
>> log2(maxSize)
ans =
    3.099999999932819e+01
```

and on a 64-bit system, it gives

```
>> [~,maxSize] = computer
maxSize =
    2.814749767106550e+14
>> log2(maxSize)
ans =
    47.999999999999993
```

So apparently, on a 32-bit system, Matlab only uses 31 bits to address elements, which gives you the upper limit.

> **If anyone can clarify why Matlab only uses 31 bits on a 32-bit system, and only *48* bits on a 64-bit system, that'd be awesome :)**

Internally, Matlab always uses linear indices to access elements in an array (it probably just uses a C-style array or so), which implies for your `adj` matrix that its final element is

```
finEl = nNodes*nNodes = 2.54016e+09
```

This, unfortunately, is larger than the maximum addressable with 31 bits. Therefore, on the 32-bit system,

```
>> adj(end) = 1;
??? Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.
```

while this command poses no problem at all on the 64-bit system.

You'll have to use a workaround on a 32-bit system:

```
nNodes = 50400;

% split sparse array up into 4 pieces
adj{1,1} = sparse(nNodes/2,nNodes/2);    adj{1,2} = sparse(nNodes/2,nNodes/2);
adj{2,1} = sparse(nNodes/2,nNodes/2);    adj{2,2} = sparse(nNodes/2,nNodes/2); 

% assign or index values to HUGE sparse arrays
function ret = indHuge(mat, inds, vals)

    % get size of cell
    sz = size(mat);

    % return current values when not given new values
    if nargin < 3
        % I have to leave this up to you...

    % otherwise, assign new values 
    else
        % I have to leave this up to you...

    end
end    

% now initialize desired elements to 1
adj = indHuge(adj, sub2ind([nNodes nNodes], ind, ind + 1),  1);
```

I just had the idea to cast all this into a proper class, so that you can use much more intuitive syntax...but that's a whole lot more than I have time for now :)

Comment: Thanks for explaining what goes on the system. Yes, my system is 32-bit system, and I am not able to access adj the last element : >> adj(nNodes * nNodes)
??? Maximum variable size allowed by the program is
exceeded.

Comment: @Swagatika: I'll include a workaround in the next edit. Refresh in 5 mins... :)

Comment: I could figure out how to create the sparse matrix, please check my answer below and let me know if you have a more optimized answer. Still accessing the last elements is a concern here...

Comment: thanks :) , but I guess, I could get a way without the need of splitting the matrix ...

Comment: @Swagatika: unless you need to fill that final element some time in the future :)

Comment: Hi. I found that the following one works: >>adj(nNodes, nNodes) = 2; But >> adj(nNodes * nNodes) does not work. Yes, if I want to use linear indexing I need to follow the method you suggested...

Comment: @Swagatika: oh wow...in that case, forget all I said about Matlab using linear indices internally; I think this is worthy of a bug report, as it is very unintuitive and undesired behavior. `adj(end)=1` does not work, while `adj(end,end)=1;` (which should be equivalent) works without any hickups!