# Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded-MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I saw some similar issues in this forum but I didn't find a real solution to this problem.

I have the following matlab code, in which I work with very big images (182MP):

```
%step 1: read the image
image=single(imread('image.tif'));

%step 2: read the image segmentation
regions=imread('image_segmentation.ppm');

%step 3: count the number of segments
number_of_regions=numel(unique(regions));

%step 4: regions label
regions_label=unique(regions);

for i=1:number_of_regions

    %pick the pixel indexes of the i'th region
    [x_region,y_region]=find(regions==label_regions(i));

    %the problem starts here

   ndvi_region=(image(x_region,y_region,1)-image(x_region,y_region,3))./(imagem(x_region,y_region,1)+image(x_region,y_region,3));
```

every time I run the code with specific regions matlab returns the error: Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.

I'm running the code with 48GB of RAM in my colllege's cluster. The problem starts only in region number 43 and below. The other regions run ok.

Is there a smart way for me to run this code?

Comment: Are you sure you need `single`? i.e., normally Matlab uses `int8` or `int16`, reducing the memory usage by a factor of 4 (or 2)... How large (in pixels) is `image.tif`?

Comment: yes I really need single, it's crucial to compute ndvi_region. image.tif has 182 Megapixels, it's a remote sensing image. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: This is what Matlab has to say about ["What is the maximum matrix size for each platform?"](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-IHYHFZ/index.html). And just the physical presence of 48GB of RAM does not mean that Matlab can access all of it.

Comment: I also found [this answer by Rody Oldenhuis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280833/errormaximum-variable-size-allowed-by-the-program-is-exceeded-while-using-sub2/13283832#13283832) to be interesting with regard to your problem.

Comment: I'm guessing [blockproc](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) is not applicable to your case?

Comment: Just a suggestion: you could also convert to `single` in-place only on the line where you compute `ndvi_region`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your use of

```
image(x_region,y_region,1)
```

I suspect that you think that accesses the N elements of the region; but in fact, you access NxN elements! For a large region, that can easily blow up on you.  In general, A(vec1, vec2) creates a section of numel(vec1) by numel(vec2). To solve this, you need to use the sub2ind function to find just the indices you need (or use a single parameter in your `find` command, and shape your matrix accordingly):

```
% option 1
[x_region, y_region]=find(regions==label_regions(i));
indx1 = sub2ind(size(image), x_region, y_region, 1*ones(size(x_region)));
indx3 = sub2ind(size(image), x_region, y_region, 3*ones(size(x_region)));
ndvi_region = (image(indx1) - image(indx3))./(image(indx1) + image(indx3));

% option 2
indx = find(regions==label_regions(i));
r_image = reshape(image, [], 3); % assuming you have XxYx3 image
ndvi_region = (r_image(indx, 1) - r_image(indx, 3))./(r_image(indx,1) + r_image(indx, 3));
```

The second option does make a complete copy of the image, so option 1 is probably quicker.

Comment: i tried your solution, but matlab gives the error: Error using sub2ind The subscript vectors must all be of the same size. I will try to fix it and give you a feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Of course - I'm sorry. Was doing this without access to a Matlab license. I believe my recent edit fixes it.

Comment: That worked for ndvi_region, thank you, but i have another question: I also have a ground truth binary image. can i access it with indx1, indx2 or create a new index as you explained? thank you again.

Comment: Glad to hear it! As for your new question: If it's a binary image, it presumably doesn't have a third dimension. I think you should be able to use the `indx` from the second option without needing to reshape (when you use a single index to index a 2d array, it will work "automagically"). I'm sure you will figure it out.

Comment: @mad: +1! In the worst case (if there are no duplicates in either `x_region` or `y_region`, this will result in a duplication of the *entire image* in memory. Given that it's a pretty large image, in combination with how memory limitations work in Matlab, this could indeed very well be the cause.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis thank you for your comments. I think the problem is now solved with Floris suggestions.